# grouper recipe but return last "group" even with uneven length

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am getting the hang of the `grouper()` recipe from `itertools`:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

This version fills the last group with a given value. If I remove `fillvalue`, then it does not return the last group if it has less than `n` elements. I have encountered several situations where I want the last group whether or not it is the same size as all the other groups. I also do not want to add any padding. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

def grouper(iterable, n):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    group = tuple(islice(iterator, n))
    while group:
        yield group
        group = tuple(islice(iterator, n))
```

If you prefer, the following is just a slight change in the logic, but it works the same:

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
     iterator = iter(iterable)
     while True:
         group = tuple(islice(iterator, n))
         if not group:
             return
         yield group
```

There are other variants here too.  For example, if you want a completely lazy version:

```
from itertools import groupby

def grouper(iterable, n):
    iterator = enumerate(iterable)
    for unused_group_number, idx_items in groupby(iterator, lambda t: t[0] // n):
        yield (item for unused_idx, item in idx_items)
```

This is likely less performant than `islice` since it does so much calling back into python, but it is completely lazy (and safe).  e.g. it yields iterators over groups and it handles the case where the caller doesn't consume every element in a group iterator.

Comment: You forgot to actually read the values from `islice()` - try `list(grouper('ABCDEFG', 3))` for example..

Comment: What is the difference between returning the iterator directly from `islice()` vs wrapping it in a tuple or list?

Comment: @eugeney Since `grouper()` is a generator, I'm aware of how to use it. I'll probably do something more along the lines of `for x in grouper('ABCDEFG', 3):`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: when `islice()` is called, it doesn't advance the original iterator. It just returns a new iterator. That's why the above example produces an infinite loop. A safer way would be to do `tuple(islice( ... ))`

Comment: @eugeney When I use the returned iterator inside the for loop as shown in my previous comment, will there still be an infinite loop? If so, why? p.s. There is no need to ping me twice with the same message.

Comment: @eugeney I get it now. (Posted from my phone while waiting for my desktop to reboot.)

Comment: @eugeney -- Yeah, you're right.  The code where I use this _does_ use `tuple` to consume elements from `islice` before yielding the group.  I've updated my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) in a loop to read the elements in chunks:

```
from itertools import islice

def grouper(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    group = tuple(islice(it, n))
    while group:
        yield group
        group = tuple(islice(it, n))    

print(list(grouper('ABCDEFG', 3)))  # [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G',)]
```

Comment: What is the difference between returning a tuple vs returning the iterator directly from `islice()`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: when `islice()` is called, it doesn't advance the original iterator. It just returns a new iterator. Omitting `tuple()` would lead to an infinite loop in the provided example.

Answer (score 1):

Since python 3.12, the functionality you are looking for is the builtin function `itertools.batched`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched

```py
import itertools

print(list(itertools.batched('ABCDEFG', 3)))  # [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G',)]
```